# What did Rachel end up concluding her wish she aimed from the tower to be?

Tags: tower-of-god

This is mainly referring to episode 13 of *[Kami no Tou](https://myanimelist.net/anime/40221/Kami_no_Tou)*. From what I remember, Rachel was debating on whether she wanted Bam to become a star, or if she wanted herself to become a star. I didn't understand or perhaps remember what she ended up choosing.

What did Rachel end up concluding her wish she aimed from the tower to be?

Answer (score 1):

Her wish was to see the stars and be treated like a princess. We don't know much about her past. She might have had some problems in her past that led her to the path that she chose to follow. As Endorsi said once to Rachel that whatever she is seeking at the top of the tower is more important than Bam.

Comment: ok, I know that. the princess with the horn said that to Rachel with what she aims to the tower to be more important than Bam. at episode 13 Rachel pushed Bam off and away looking like she killed him then we had the time of going back to the beginning to see how this started. during that time we saw her side of all that happened with her thoughts. of course it was rushed to fit in one episode, but I didn't understand what her wish was. 

with what you said I am unsure if you have watched episode 13 to give that answer.

Comment: I have watched the entire series and read the manhwa up to the end of the season. As i said we don't have enough information, unless you are a person who read the entire manhwa